# what is splint trying to tell me in this?

Tags: c

I wrote a simple code (part of it below) and use splint to check for any warnings. But Splint is complaining. What might be the issue I am missing?

**Splint Warning**

```
malloctest.c:24:3: Return value (type char *) ignored: gets(p)
  Result returned by function call is not used. If this is intended, can cast
  result to (void) to eliminate message. (Use -retvalother to inhibit warning)
```

**Code part**

```
p= (char*)malloc(BUFFER*sizeof(char));

    if(p==NULL)
        {
            printf("the memory could not be allocated");
        }
    else
    {
        gets(p);  //line 24
        printf("the name entered is \n%s\n",p);
    }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: don't cast malloc see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`gets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) returns a `char*` to indicate success or failure, which the code is ignoring hence the warning.

However, with `gets()` there is no way to prevent buffer overrun. Instead, you can use [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) with `"%Ns"` format specifier (or [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) if the string can contain spaces):

```
if (1 == scanf("%9s", p)) /* if BUFFER(_SIZE ?) was 10.
                             The 'N' in the format specifier
                             must be 1 less than size of
                             the buffer to allow for null
                             terminator. */
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using `gets()`, **always!**

`gets()` is a very unsafe function because it doesn't check the length of the buffer and this could lead into a potential buffer overflow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char buffer[10];
  gets(buffer);
  puts(buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

If you for example input `0123456789 10 11 12 13`  then you have a **big** problem.

It is better to use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char buffer[10];
  fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
  puts(buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that C11 has [gets_s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) as a replacement.

Comment: and when will C11 be ever supported? Afaik c99 is still not widely by all major C-compilers (unless I'm very much mistaken)

I find `fgets` more elegenat anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[gets(p)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/gets/) has a char* return value which you aren't storing. This isn't realy a problem but splint just reminds you of that.